# How to modify value in attributes sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a query like this :

```
const rows = await Leaderboard.findAll({
      where: {
        app_type_id: appId,
        ...filterWhereQuery,
        emp_id: dataProgress.submited
      },
      include: [
        ...leaderboardFavouriteInclude,
        {
          model: UserEmployee,
          as: 'user',
          attributes: ['emp_id', 'emp_full_name', 'emp_email', 'is_invited', ...empInfo]
        },
```

I want to modify the `emp_email` value in `UserEmployee` model. The email is would be return like `abc@gmail.com` but i want to remove the domain email and the result is should be `abc` for the `emp_email`.

How to solve case like that ? Thanks

Comment: find index of @ in email: `email.indexOf('@')`, and use slice to get modified email: `email.slice(index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a getter for a `emp_email` field like this:

```js
  emp_email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    get() {
      const rawValue = this.getDataValue('emp_email');
      return rawValue ? rawValue.split('@')[0] : null;
    }
  }
```